# Youtube "live chat" direct url

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I must download (using cURL) and process (PHP) chat messages from youtube live videos but I did manage to find the url for only the so called "Top Chat". What parameter should be included to get the "Live Chat" (unfiltered messages) instead?
A typical URL to download the "Top Chat" looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?continuation=0ofMyANxGlhDaWtxSndvWVZVTk5jRzR4Y1V4MVpFWXRlbUkwVFRSaWNYaE1TV0ozRWd0SWNGcEJaWG95YjFselFSb1Q2cWpkdVFFTkNndEljRnBCWlhveWIxbHpRU0FCMAGCAQIIBIgBAaABgL6nuLjs8AKyAQA%253D

The Live chat can be accessed by selecting "Live chat" on the top left where it says "Top chat"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, the `Live Chat` is only loaded via subsequent Ajax calls, paginated and updated in realtime. There's not a single URL to download all the messages AFAIK.

I would suggest to use the [official Google Apis](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages) to do this.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. Unfortunately, I need to highlight the messages that were hidden from Top Chat by youtube and are only visible in the Live Chat of dozens of high traffic channels for an analysis of the youtube decision-making process and I doubt that these channels will grant me access to their data through the API.
Thank you very much