# Youtube API - Get chat messages of archived livestreams?

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

How do I get chat messages from livestreams after they are completed (using the Youtube data API)? These chat messages normally appear next to the livestream or video of completed livestream.
I can use the [LiveChatMessages: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) to get the chats of live livestreams, but it gives an error when the livestream is completed.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The live chat is no longer live.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The live chat is no longer live.",
        "domain": "youtube.liveChat",
        "reason": "liveChatEnded"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120224/retrieiving-youtube-chat-data-from-archived-completed-livestream), but there are no answers.

Comment: I'd suggest to file a feature request to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.